# Prove that $f$ is analytic and derivatives of all order $f_n^{(k)}$ converge to $f^{ (k)}$ uniformly on any compact subset of $G$.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, analyticity

Suppose $f_n$ is analytic in some region $G$ and suppose $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on
any compact subset of $G$. Prove that $f$ is analytic and derivatives of all order $f_n^{(k)}$ converge
to $f^{
(k)}$ uniformly on any compact subset of $G$.

I know this is a classical result. I just don't know where I can find proofs of this result. Any solutions or links are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pretty much every introduction to complex analysis should have a proof of it. Clearly, it suffices to prove the case $k = 1$.

Comment: Write it as an integral and use Cauchy estimates for a uniform bound.